# Create node programmatically with menu entries

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, routes

I created an action in Rules, which generates a duplicate of a node. If I am creating a node of the type "basic", it will duplicate the node for every taxonomy term. So when I have a node with three taxonomy terms, the action will generate three nodes.

The only difference are the taxonomy terms, because the created nodes should get the URL `'/taxonomy-term1/node-title', '/taxonomy-term2/node-title', ...`

My problem: If I have the taxonomy terms Taxonomy_Term1, Taxonomy_Term2 and Taxonomy_Term3, I get the following result:

```
/taxonomy-term1/node-title

/default/node-title

/default/node-title-0
```

I am thinking the problem lies in the array which was created from the latest nid. But when I am printing each term_name (to know what it looks like), the results are the Strings Taxonomy_Term1, Taxonomy_Term2 and so on.

```
function autocreatenode_rules_action() {
$nid = db_query_range("SELECT nid FROM {node} ORDER BY nid DESC", 0, 1)->   fetchField();
$string = token_replace('[node:field_tags]', array('node' => node_load($nid)));
$terms = explode(',', $string);
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $term_name) {
    $i++;
}
    if($i >= 2) {
        foreach ($terms as $term_name) {
            $node = new stdClass(); 
            $node->type = 'basic';  
            $node->language = 'de';  
            node_object_prepare($node);  
            $node->title = 'Title';
            $node->field_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Something in the body';
            $menu = array();
            $menu['link_title'] = 'Menu Link title';
            $menu['description'] = '';
            $menu['menu_name'] = 'main-menu';

            switch($term_name) {
                case 'Taxonomy_Term1':
                    $menu['plid'] = 5;
                    break;
                case 'Taxonomy_Term2':
                    $menu['plid'] = 6;
                    break;
                case 'Taxonomy_Term3':
                    $menu['plid'] = 7;
                    break;
                default:
                    $menu['plid'] = 1;
            }

            $menu['enabled'] = 1;
            $node->menu = $menu;
            $node->status = 1;
            $node->promote = 0;
            $node->sticky = 0;
            $node->comment = 2;
            $node->uid = 1;
            $node->date = 'complaint_post_date';
            $node->created = strtotime('complaint_post_date');
            $node = node_submit($node);
            node_save($node);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: What does your pathauto configuration look like? This is where the URLs are generated, right?

Comment: I am using tokens in my pathauto
[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]/[node:title]

Comment: Hey @Meito, is this question resolved? Did the answer below resolve it?

Comment: Yes, my question is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems a bit frail at places, but if it works for you, we can focus on your specific question.

The main problem is that you are not adding the $menu array to your node object before saving it. You would only need to add it to the object before you save it, similar to this:

```
$node->menu = $menu;
...
node_save($node);
```

Cheers and good luck!

P.S.: You can check out this thread for some code examples https://stackoverflow.com/q/2603289/5875098
P.S.2: To get all the terms directly from the $node object:

```
$terms = array();
$language = 'und'; // or will be provided by some Drupal hooks
foreach ($node->field_tags[$language] as $delta => $value) {
  $termObj = taxonomy_term_load($value['tid']);
  $terms[] = $termObj->name;
}
```

You can replace the $terms = explode... in your code with this snippet.

Comment: I edited my post with the proper use of $node->menu, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Then the next possible problem is the plid numbers you use, 5,6,7 should be existing menu items ids in your main-menu. Can you check this?

Comment: The plid numbers exist. When I am changing $terms to something simpel like $terms = array('Taxonomy_Term1','Taxonomy_Term2','Taxonomy_Term3'), it works just fine.

Comment: That means that the token_replace/string manipulation part could be causing the problem. If you get a nid, you could also, as an alternative, load the node and then its terms through the field_tags field. This would be more reliable codewise, you will have a direct access to the node's values, instead of hiding things inside token replacements and exploding strings. :-)

Comment: I am using the token_replace/string, because I do not know how to get the terms through the field_tags field. I tried $terms = $node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'], but that is probably the wrong way

Comment: Add P.S.2 with a little snippet showing how to do this. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: It works and problem solved :-) Thank you very much.
I understand most of the snippet except for the delta part. It is not clear to me what delta stands for.

Comment: The field field_tag  is a multivalue field, the delta gives you access to each value, in your case each term. Happy ending! N.B.: You should accept the answer if it solved the problem.